# Частота обновлений игрового мира

Tags: c++, разработка-игр, sfml

Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать детерминированное обновление игровой логики? 
Например 60 раз в секунду. 
Использую sfml + C++ 
Не знаю в какую сторону рыть, пробовал искать статьи на эту тему, но либо я плохо искал, либо совершенно не то.

Может есть хорошие статьи\туториалы на эту тему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно тут 2 выбора.

1) Усыпить поток после обновления на примерно 0.016 (6) секунд (если нужно совсем точно, можно посчитать сколько ушло на обработку и подогнать)

2) Использовать более высокоуровневый API и установить callback, чтобы выполнялся каждые 0.016 (6) секунд.

Значение 0.016 (6) секунд это сколько отводится максимум на 1 кадр при 60 кадрах в секунду, то есть (1 / 60). В обоих случаях надо учитывать, что 0.016 (6) вмещает в себя `update()` и `render()`

Comment: Вы знаете, что то я видимо не вкурил.. 
У вас нет под рукой примера установки колбэка с задержкой? 
Или может быть если статья на примете? 

Спасибо.

Comment: Я не использовал sfml, поэтому не могу сказать как это делается в нем. Вот здесь туториал про время в sfml - http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/1.6/window-time.php В SDL это делается при помощи SDL_AddTimer() - https://github.com/AlmasB/StarshipFontana/blob/master/src/Main.cpp

Comment: Есть еще вариант использовать sf::RenderWindow::setFramerateLimit()